# What's the meaning of 'DNS Proxy' suffix appeared in iOS console log

Tags: ios, xcode

While in debugging network related Apps, I saw there are a lot of **DNS Proxy**  system logs related to network changed event, but they come with different optional suffix ***, !, +, -***, such as **DNS Proxy, DNS! Proxy!**.

What's the exactly meaning of these suffix?

```
configd[32] <Notice>: network changed: v4(pdp_ip0:10.223.187.168) DNS* Proxy  
configd[32] <Notice>: network changed: v4(utun0+:10.171.255.254, en0, pdp_ip0) DNS! Proxy!
configd[48] <Notice>: network changed: v4(en0!:192.168.53.107, pdp_ip0) DNS! Proxy+
configd[48] <Notice>: network changed: v4(pdp_ip0+:10.188.2.249) DNS+ Proxy
configd[48] <Notice>: network changed: DNS- Proxy
configd[48] <Notice>: network changed: v4(en0!:192.168.53.106, pdp_ip0) DNS! Proxy+
```

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com